# Sentence construction Using Took and Had Taken

Tags: sentence-construction

Which statement construction is correct?

> a) He did not provide her service even though he **had taken** Rs 500 from her as an advance.
>
> b) He did not provide her service even though he **took** Rs 500 from her as an advance.

I feel sentence (a) is more correct as it gives detailed idea about first past (i.e., money taken) by using past perfect. Sentence (b) is more informative.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, although (b) (*even though he took*) is more popular in informal (everyday) speech, while (a) (*even though he had taken*) is more popular in written English.

Comment: [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=even+though+he+had+taken%2Ceven+though+he+took%2Ceven+though+she+had+taken%2Ceven+though+she+took%2C+even+if+he+had+taken%2C+even+if+he+took&year_start=1965&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) would suggest that the “had took” version is more popular in written works.